# Chrome extension that changes values in the Preferences file

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a chrome extension that auto-hides the bookmark bar and shows it when you hover over that area. I was able to do this through c++ by listening to the cursor location and using the ctrl-shift-b shortcut. Unfortunately this is not feasible using the extensions API so I'll have to find another solution.

Would it be possible to do this by changing the value of show_on_all_tabs to true in Preferences?

"bookmark_bar":{"show_apps_shortcut":false,"show_on_all_tabs":false}

If so, then how would I go about implementing that in my extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no API available to Google Chrome extensions to change/hook/control the browser UI.
Other Chromium-based browsers may have something of the kind like Opera's sidebar API.

Changing any of the internal files like the `Preferences` is also not allowed.  It's hard to change even externally as you'd need to change `Secure Preferences` too, properly updating its hashsum.

Sending <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> hotkey from inside an extension/webpage is fruitless as well as it will never escape the content sandbox, and won't reach the browser's internal event listener.